# Unable to perform OCR for PDF Files having Content Copying set to Not Allowed

Tags: java, pdf, ocr, nuance

Due to security reasons, I cannot upload the PDF File, but one can create a pdf file having Content Copying set to Not Allowed, and then try to perform OCR for this file.
OCR returns an error saying the file is password protected or something similar.

Can someone tell me if there is a way I can perform OCR for such a file?

Answer (score 1):

In case you’re not familiar with the PDF password protection, then let me tell you that there are basically two types:

- **Owner password:**

  - Owner password restricts some basic functions like printing, editing, copying text and images, and so on. If your PDF document is protected with the owner or permission password then you’ll see the word “Secured” in the title bar when you open the file in the Adobe Reader.
- **User password:**

  - If a pdf is protected with user password then you can’t open that pdf without entering the right password.

Now after understanding about PDF password types let’s talk about the method to break or crack them.

- **Method 1: [Take a screenshot and run it through an OCR program](https://pdf.wondershare.com/how-to/copy-secured-pdf.html#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20%22OCR%22%20tool%20in,text%20from%20secured%20pdf%20file.)**
- **Method 2: [Use some PDF password remover to unlock your PDF file](https://www.mypdfsolutions.com/how-to-unlock-secured-pdf-file.html)**

*Adapted from [this post](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-copy-text-from-secured-pdf)*

Comment: Thank you for this answer.
Now the issue is that I want to perform the fix in JAVA itself.
I have uploaded the pdf file on my website, and the file is having content-copying set to Not Allowed. 
Can I remove the Owner Password through JAVA itself, as this website is used by my Clients, and they would not want to do the extra work of taking a screenshot or unlocking the pdf file through some software and then uploading it?

So, is removing the password security of content-copying possible through JAVA?